# Stacking Context: Putting one child div above another

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

I'm not quite understanding what rule of stacking context I am not understanding here. I have a 'divider' line ('divider-line') that I want to put behind a box div ('block').

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="report-title">
  <div class="divider-line"></div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="icon">0</div>
    <h1 class="text">FOO BAR</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS(w/ scss nesting):

```
.report-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px 0;

  .block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 200px;
    width: 475px;
    .icon {
      font-size: 9rem;
    }
    .text {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  .divider-line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
}
```

The HTML context, having 'divider-line' child come before it's sibling 'block' should put it behind no? The z-index of 10 on 'block' doesn't do anything, and I've tried putting a z-index of -1 on 'divider-line' as well (to no avail).

Any advice or direction would be great,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the z-index in you example, adding a background colour to the block shows that the divider is behind the block.

```css
.report-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  top: -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 475px;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 9rem;
}

.text {
  display: block;
}
 
.divider-line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="report-title">
  <div class="divider-line"></div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="icon">0</div>
    <h1 class="text">FOO BAR</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```